# Retrieving keys from a name value pair array in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, key-value

I have an array with values similar to below:

```
def fieldValuesArray = []
fieldValuesArray << ["key1":"value1"]
fieldValuesArray << ["key2":"value2"]
```

I would like to retrieve the key values of the array while iterating through it, like

```
fieldValuesArray.each{
    println(it.key())//key1,key2 etc.
}
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thank you,
LJ

Answer (score 0):

In your original question you are asking to access a key-value-pair. Those structures are called `map`s in Groovy. What you are doing in your first line though, is, to create an array not a map.
Furthermore accessing key value pairs with an each loop could require 2 iteration variables: key and value. Just in case you will need both inside the loop it is easier to read for me. But probably a matter of taste.

Your answer is also not a good approach in my opinion. As you first declare `fieldValuesArray` as an array and in next line you re-assign it to an initialized map. What looks more correct me is the following:

```
def fieldValuesArray = [:]
fieldValuesArray << ["key1":"value1"]
fieldValuesArray << ["key2":"value2"]

fieldValuesArray.each{ key, value -> println "${key}:${value}" }
// or
// fieldValuesArray.each{ println it.key }
```

**Please note the first line definition with `[:]` rather than `[]` and my each-closure.**